# Firebase Crashlytics build error: "could not find io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1"

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, react-native

I was trying to integrate Firebase Crashlytics on my react native app but got this error while building the app.

> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApp'.
>
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1.
>        Searched in the following locations: 
>       https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.26.1/gradle-1.26.1.pom        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.26.1/gradle-1.26.1.jar
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.26.1/gradle-1.26.1.pom
>         https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.26.1/gradle-1.26.1.jar
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.26.1/gradle-1.26.1.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.26.1/gradle-1.26.1.jar
>
> Required by:
>            project :
>
> - Try:

I've added `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'` in `dependencies` and

> maven {
>             url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
>        }

in `repositories` in `build.gradle` as suggested in documentation.

Comment: current version i am using is 1.27.0 try to achieve this

Answer (score 40):

Before, I got the same issue because I moved the `url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'` to the wrong place

I guess you guy also same. My working `build.grande` is

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        // Additional repository for fabric resources
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // Add fabric classpath
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Yes,before i pasted it inside allprojects{},now it works

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#set-up-a-library-subproject) of the fabric integration.

Try using this as a sub-library of the project.

In your app's Gradle mention the below code. It will work.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Comment: I've added as like in the documentation but it says it couldn't find on those locations. When visiting those urls on the browser, they don't exist. Is it searching on wrong urls? How to fix that?

Comment: can you please add all your gradle files?

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that everything in the documentation that should be in the project-level  build.gradle file  is there and make sure everything that should be in app-level build.gradle file is there.

Do not interchange anything.